# Is there a way to find something using RegEx then start a second search from that point?

Tags: python, regex

For example if I have a txt with something like this:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 1
Item 4
Item 1
```

I want to find each occurrence of Item 1 after Item 3

Comment: Why don't you search for "Item 3 \nItem 1" ?

Answer (score 0):

This will work for all the occurrences where Item 1 is directly below Item 3.

```
re.findall(r'Item 3\s*Item 1', a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find each occurrence of `Item 1` after the *first* occurrence of `Item 3`, you could use `re.sub` along with `re.findall`:

```py
inp = """Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 1
Item 4
Item 1"""

inp = re.sub(r'^.*?\Item 3\s+', '', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
matches = re.findall(r'\bItem 1\b', inp)
print(matches)  # ['Item 1', 'Item 1']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to find occurrence(s) of `Item 1` that is/are immediately after `Item 3`, you can use:

```
re.findall(r'(?:Item 3)\s*(Item 1)', text)
```

---

```
text = """Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 1
Item 4
Item 1"""


re.findall(r'(?:Item 3)\s*(Item 1)', text)

['Item 1']
```

```
text2 = """Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 1
Item 4
Item 3
Item 1
Item 1"""


re.findall(r'(?:Item 3)\s*(Item 1)', text2)

['Item 1', 'Item 1']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do somthing like this.

First split the text by `Item 3` only once and take the second part

```
text_of_interest = text.split("Item 3", maxsplit=1)[1]
```

Now we should have the text after "Item 3". Now we can apply regex to find all `Item 1`s.

```
items = re.findall("Item 1", text_of_interest)
```

Full Code:

```
import re

text = '''Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 1
Item 4
Item 1'''


text_of_interest = text.split("Item 3", maxsplit=1)[1]


items = re.findall("Item 1", text_of_interest)
print(items)
```

It prints `['Item 1', 'Item 1']` as expected.